# Redefining abstract env -- but keeping translations!

Tags: environments, abstract

I wanted to redefine the (article class) abstract environment, to get a result similar to that llncs, that is, with the title in bold in the first line of the body of the abstract: "\textbf{Abstract} Lorem ipsum..."

However, I also wanted to maintain the original name; and moreover ensure that babel/polyglossia still are able to translate "Abstract" appropriately. I'm not sure how to do that with the relevant code from llncs.cls:

```
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \list{}{\advance\topsep by0.35cm\relax\small
  \leftmargin=1cm
  \labelwidth=\z@
  \listparindent=\z@
  \itemindent\listparindent
  \rightmargin\leftmargin}\item[\hskip\labelsep
                                \bfseries\abstractname]}
{\endlist}
```

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you think this code will break the translation?

Comment: as long as you use `\abstractname` not the literal string `Abstract` babel and polyglossia will translate it as needed.

Comment: The `abstract` package has  a `runin` option which should do what you want.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, that's precisely what I needed!